# Western film with anachronistic weapons in a secret cave

Tags: story-identification, movie

This is a war movie about a group of men being chasing by an Apache group that is using spears and arrows with horses. They end up running to the secret cave... then they decide to go in the cave and found a modern weapon which is like an M-16 grenade, etc that shouldn't exist in that era. They start to learn to use the modern weapon that is found in this mysterious secret cave to fight back.

Comment: Do you know with any degree of certainty if the weapons used were actually M16s with grenade launchers? That would help narrow it down. Also, what is a "Lyn apache"?

Comment: @SpaceWolf1701 whoops the “Lyn apache” was my phone being seriously weird when I edited.

Comment: the story is about a group of man being chased by cruel bad guys ...i think its 90 s or 20s movie because they using horses ...and the weapon they found in the unknown secret place is a modern weapon like ak..m16 hand grenade ...i still remember one of them trying to learning how to use a hand grenade by reading a guide book....i think its not an apache gang i just dont remember what the movies namee but the storyline just like that...i think im seeing this movie at years between 2010-2015 so its not kinda old tho

Comment: You could improve this question by going through the checklists [here](https://scifi.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9335/how-to-ask-a-good-story-id-question) and editing in any relevant info you can think to add.

Comment: Sounds a bit like [Cowboys vs Aliens](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cowboys_%26_Aliens#Plot) (but not quite)...

Comment: Do you know whether this was actually set in a time period of spears and arrows (I labeled it as "western" based on your description) or if this turns out to be some sort of far future or post-apocalypse?

Comment: yes its a spear and arrow but it has cross over with the modern weapon

Answer (score 1):

The mix of Cowboys and high technology in the 1970’s TV show Cliffhangers?   Being chased, stumbling into a cave, and finding weapons.

The Secret Empire – Set in the 1880 and inspired by the 1935 Gene Autry film serial The Phantom Empire, Geoffrey Rush would star as U.S. Marshal Jim Donner who, while investigating a mysterious band of phantom riders, stumbles upon an alien city deep beneath the Earth. Scenes in the subterranean city would be broadcast in color while the above ground scenes featured a sepia tone.

https://www.tvobscurities.com/articles/cliffhangers/

Comment: it has colour on that movies its not old as 70s maybe its in 2000-2010 movies funny fact ive been searching this movie for years ...im seeing this movie like 2 times only before but what i know is the story is about a group of survivor that being chase by bad guys that using horses,spear,and arrow...to chase them down ...and they end up in a secret place that has a modern weapon that shouldnt exist in that era because what the enemy using is spear and arrow...they started to learn how to use the advance weapon to fight their enemy back in other to achieve victory and survive